# Xcode 4.2.1 Code Folding

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, xcode4.2

I've got a really frustrating issue in Xcode 4.2.1 on OS X Lion, where the code folding doesn't seem to work, or at least hardly every with no obvious reason.

The default keyboard shortcuts are supposed to be:

```
Fold Methods/Functions      ⇧⌘⌥⌘←      shift+option+command+left
Unfold Methods/Functions    ⇧⌘⌥⌘→      shift+option+command+right
```

.. but I just get the Homer ('Doh'), error sound all the times I try it.

I always make sure I have the correct pane selected (before anyone asks ;o), and have also tried the following, with no luck:

```
- With & without Assistant editor enabled
- In a total separate editing window
- By selecting 'Code Folding >> Fold Methods & functions' from the Editor menu
- Changing the keyboard shortcut (Even tho no conflict was showing)
```

The only clue I have, and I'm not sure if it's related, is that whenever I press the '*option*' key in the editing view my cursor changes to a **+** (or crosshair) - It only does this in the editing views of Xcode, however I don't think this is the issue as if I change the shortcut to not use the '*option*' key, it still doesn't work.

Anyone got any ideas, as it's driving me barmy & my searches haven't come up with anything??

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally resolved to totally remove Xcode, clear out prefs and then re-install.

This seems to have fixed the issue (So far at least)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Xcode 3 won't fold unless syntax highlighting is turned on. I don't like syntax highlighting, so for lack of a better alternative I use 'View->Syntax Coloring->Simple Coloring', which only highlights comments and numbers.